# Print jobs are getting stuck in the queues of the printers on the Print server (Windows server 2016)

Tags: windows, drivers, printer, queue, pdf

Print jobs are getting stuck in the queues of the printers on the Print server (Windows server 2016)
The printout are being printed only after the affected printers are physically restarted.
The printers are Industrial Zebra (different models) . Not all printers are affected (only some of them randomly)
We are using a driver package that contains drivers for multiple Zebra models (NiceLabels)
We have tried with a different version of the NiceLabels package but we have the same problem.
We have tried with a version of the official Zebra package but the problem persists.
The printouts are coming in a pdf format and are sent to the print spooler by an local application.

The problem happens randomly. In some periods appears almost daily , in other times it happens that we have a few weeks without an occurrence.